# unsetting field via view hooks no effect on aggregation results

Tags: views, hooks

I have created a view, with some aggregation parameters.

I expected that unsetting (removing) the aggregation field via some view hook (views_pre_render?) would do the trick to disable the aggregation caused by this field.

But it just removes the field from the table, the results are the same (aggregated by the unsetted field, even if it is removed).

some ideas? thanks

Comment: I don't know the answer of the top of my head, but if you export the view with and without aggregation settings, you might get an idea of what to change. I'd suggest that `hook_views_pre_render()` is a bit late to be doing the change because the query's already been built and run.

Comment: Thanks Andy, with pre_build worked fine and the aggregation disappears.

    function views_test_views_pre_build(&$view) {

        unset($view->field['my_field']);

      }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with pre_build worked fine and the aggregation disappears.

function views_test_views_pre_build(&$view) { unset($view->field['my_field']); }